# Is there a ruby method that just returns the value of a block?

Tags: ruby, block

I know about `Object#tap`, which takes a value and returns that value. But is there a method that takes a block and returns the value evaluated by the block?

To improve my code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182722/how-do-i-swap-array-elements-using-parallel-assignment/4341001#4341001) (which is more complicated than the snippet below), I'd like to change

```
deck.index("A").tap {|index| 
  STDERR.puts "Result of indexing for #{"A".inspect} is #{index.inspect}"
}
```

, which has `"A"` repeated, into

```
def my_method(*args)
  yield *args
end

deck = ['A', 'B', 'C']
my_method("A") {|value| deck.index(value).tap {|index|
  STDERR.puts "Result of indexing for #{value.inspect} is #{index.inspect}"
} }
# Result of indexing for "A" is 0
# => 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is essentially the equivalent of `let` in Lisp or OCaml — something that allows you to temporarily bind a value to an identifier without introducing a new variable into the larger scope. There isn't anything that lets you do such a thing with that syntax in Ruby. The equivalent Ruby would be:

```
lambda {|value| deck.index(value).tap {|index|
  STDERR.puts "Result of indexing for #{value.inspect} is #{index.inspect}"
} }.call 'A'
```

You could of course just write a method like:

```
def let(*values) 
  yield *values 
end
```

Comment: Is it possible to put `'A'` near the start, rather than near the end?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could solve it with fibers. Something like:

```
def myfiber
    block = lambda{nil}
    loop{ block = Fiber.yield(block.call) } 
end
f = Fiber.new {myfiber }
f.resume

puts "result: #{f.resume(lambda{1})}"
puts "result: #{f.resume(lambda{5})}"
puts "result: #{f.resume(lambda{2})}"
```

will result in:

```
result: 1
result: 5
result: 2
```