# How to get a reference to a 'dynamic' object call?

Tags: ruby, arrays

Well, my question is not very clear, but what I want to do is the following:

```
average = [1, 2, 3].inject(0) { |sum, el| sum + el } / this.size
```

The code above won't work because of the ridiculous call to **this**, But what I want to accomplish is to get a reference to the array to which I'm calling inject on. (in this case [1, 2, 3]), Given my ignorance in ruby I did it with **this**. But, Could you please tell me how to do it right? 
Is it possible at all to do it without a variable reference?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Probably related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4341161/is-there-a-ruby-method-that-just-returns-the-value-of-a-block

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no this in ruby the nearest thing is self.

Here are some examples to help you on your way

```
#example 1 not self needed numbers is the array

numbers = [1, 2, 3]

numbers.reduce(:+).to_f / numbers.size

# example 2 using tap which gives access to self and returns self
# hence why total variable is needed

total = 0
[1, 2, 3].tap {|a| total = a.reduce(:+).to_f / a.size }

# instance_eval hack which accesses self, and the block after do is an expression 
# can return the average without an extra variable

[1, 2, 3].instance_eval { self.reduce(:+).to_f / self.size } # => 2.0
```

So far I prefer example 1

Comment: Yep... but he would like to it without a variable reference. It's the main requirement...

Comment: lucapette is right. I'm playing with Ruby to get better at it, and I wondered If I could do it, in the way I described. thanks !

Comment: Well, in your latest case, the expression returns an array, instead of the float value of an average calculation.

Comment: user766388 yes but it sets total too

Comment: Your last example is as close as it gets, so, kudos for that one, and thanks for the lesson Mr. Kyburz!

Comment: If you are really a Ruby beginner, there's no point trying to learn tricky code like this, IMHO

Comment: Please do explain Why John? I've been asked to do tricky things in Ruby interviews. However you seem to know where the line is drawn between what's useful and what's pointless.

Comment: You don't need to specify `self.` in your last snippet, and it's not hackish IMO.

Comment: Mladen Jablanović agreed, it was to more to show what self is

Answer (score 0):

'this' doesn't refer to the array, so that won't work at all. I don't think it's possible to get a reference to the array as you have declared it. But you will never run into such a problem, because if the array is hardwired into the code like that, then the divisor might as well be too, so you can just write '/3' at the end.

In the general case where you have an array of unknown size, you would also have a name for the array, so you could use that. Like:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
average = a.inject(0) {|sum, el| sum+el} / a.size
```

Comment: So, the short answer is that ruby doesn't have such capability?
And I agree that I'm certainly not going to need it anyways. I just wanted to know if the language had a syntax for it.