# Refer to anonymous array within each/block

Tags: ruby, arrays, block, each, enumerable

I have the following in Ruby:

```
arr = [1, 2]
arr.each{|n| arr << n unless n > 2_000}
```

Is there any way to reference my array from within the block if I define it anonymously?

```
[1,2].each{|n| self << n unless n > 2_000}
```

Or something?  I'm guessing not because I can't think of a way that I would reference it.

Comment: 1) no, you can't. 2) **DO NOT** modify collection you're iterating.

Comment: @Sergio Tulentsev, 1) you can always write your own iterator that passes `self` as a parameter to given block 2) was Matz wrong by adding map!, flatten! etc to ruby? ps. no offense, just a discussion :)

Comment: @trushkevich: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quod_licet_Iovi,_non_licet_bovi, I guess :)

Comment: @Sergio Tulentsev, haha, you are right :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here are similar (although outdated) questions:

[Call to iterating object from iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7511716/call-to-iterating-object-from-iterator)

[How to get a reference to a 'dynamic' object call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7284637/how-to-get-a-reference-to-a-dynamic-object-call/7284670#7284670)

also you could create a one-liner this way:

```
(arr = [1, 2]).each{|n| arr << n unless n > 2_000}
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing the array when you are iterating it may cause infinite loop.

You could do below:

```
arr = [1, 2]
arr += arr.select { |n| n <= 2000 }
```

Comment: Bummer, that ruins my Project Euler fibonnaci solution: `arr.each{|x| arr << arr[-1] + fib[-2] unless x > 4_000_000 }.select{|n| n % 2 == 0}.reduce(:+)`

Answer (score 0):

```
[].tap { |e| e.concat([1,2,20000].select { |n| n <= 2000 })
```